# How to get absolute path with TestDataFactory in Katalon Studio

Tags: git, webdriver, katalon-studio, test-data

I used to have a excel sheet bound to my test case by

```
def dataUserPass = TestDataFactory.findTestData("myTable")
```

where "myTable" is relative id of a file located at `C:/Users/myself/git/my-project/Data Files/myTable`.

Recently I moved my code to a server using Gitlab. Tests run fine on my computer, but when a co-worker tries to run this test they get this error message:

> Test FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find test data with id 'Data Files/myTable' because (of) 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\myself\git\my-project\Data Files\myTable.xlsx'

So I tried to redefine my test data with:

```
def dataUserPass = TestDataFactory.findTestData(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + '/Data Files/myTable')
```

(`RunConfiguration.getProjectDir()` returns `C:\Users\myself\git\my-project\`)

But I got the following:

> Test FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find test data with id 'Data Files/C:/Users/myself/git/my-project/Data Files/myTable' because (of) 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test data with id 'Data Files/C:/Users/myself/git/my-project/Data Files/myTable' does not exist'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add the excel file in the same folder with your "myTable" file in Data Files folder. Then in the data-file mapping, choose "Relative path". 
This setting will help your project locate the file using relative path and will can be executed from different machines.

Answer (score 1):

I think getSourceUrl method will solve your problem. Try something like this

```
def dataUserPass = TestDataFactory.findTestData("myTable")
println dataUserPass.getSourceUrl()
```